# php switch case statement to handle ranges

Tags: php, range, switch-statement

I'm parsing some text and calculating the weight based on some rules. All the characters have the same weight. This would make the switch statement really long can I use ranges in the case statement.

I saw one of the answers advocating associative arrays.

```
$weights = array(
[a-z][A-Z] => 10,
[0-9] => 100,
['+','-','/','*'] => 250
);
//there are more rules which have been left out for the sake of clarity and brevity
$total_weight = 0;
foreach ($text as $character)
{
  $total_weight += $weight[$character];
}
echo $weight;
```

What is the best way to achieve something like this?
Is there something similar to the bash case statement in php?
Surely writing down each individual character in either the associative array or the switch statement can't be the most elegant solution or is it the only alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = 'This is a test 123 + 3';

$patterns = array (
    '/[a-zA-Z]/' => 10,
    '/[0-9]/'   => 100,
    '/[\+\-\/\*]/' => 250
);

$weight_total = 0;
foreach ($patterns as $pattern => $weight)
{
    $weight_total += $weight * preg_match_all ($pattern, $str, $match);;
}

echo $weight_total;
```

**UPDATE: with default value **

```
foreach ($patterns as $pattern => $weight)
{
    $match_found = preg_match_all ($pattern, $str, $match);
    if ($match_found)
    {
        $weight_total += $weight * $match_found;
    }
    else
    {
        $weight_total += 5; // weight by default
    }
}
```

Comment: In this how do I add a default case. Say something isn't found and I want to assign it a fixed weight.

Comment: Found something that doesn't match any of the cases.
Right now it doesn't get any weight assigned but I want a non zero default value.

Answer (score 194):

Well, you can have ranges in switch statement like:

```
//just an example, though
$t = "2000";
switch (true) {
  case  ($t < "1000"):
    alert("t is less than 1000");
  break
  case  ($t < "1801"):
    alert("t is less than 1801");
  break
  default:
    alert("t is greater than 1800")
}

//OR
switch(true) {
   case in_array($t, range(0,20)): //the range from range of 0-20
      echo "1";
   break;
   case in_array($t, range(21,40)): //range of 21-40
      echo "2";
   break;
}
```

Comment: Very good!. But nobody can accept this. 40 againts 1 vote. Bet you earn some bedge.

Comment: just to explain the `(true)` in 1st bit of the switch, this now is the `other side` of all the comparisons i.e. is 1,2 or 3 in the array? if it is it will return a `true`. And `true`, is the `condition` inside the upper line of the switch, so it works

Comment: This is a great solution, by far the best I've seen anywhere. If you're looking for a great answer, ignore the accepted one. I've wanted something like this for years, and never thought to actually see if it was possible, this is the best way I've ever seen to avoid endless loops or if/elseif structures. My case: case stri_str($test_value,'test string'): works like a charm.

Comment: This a good solution, but in my case my range are from 0 to 1000 and for five levels (so the number can be between 0 to 5000). The solution with the `range()` will generate five array of 1000 elements, so is this solution a good idea or not ? If somebody drop by and can answer this, feel free :)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the character range using regular expression. This saves from writing a really long switch case list. For example,

```
function find_weight($ch, $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $pat => $weight) {
        if (preg_match($pat, $ch)) {
            return $weight;
        }   
    }   
    return 0;
}

$weights = array(
'/[a-zA-Z]/' => 10, 
'/[0-9]/'    => 100,
'/[+\\-\\/*]/'   => 250 
);
//there are more rules which have been left out for the sake of clarity and brevity
$total_weight = 0;
$text = 'a1-';
foreach (str_split($text) as $character)
{
  $total_weight += find_weight($character, $weights);
}
echo $total_weight; //360
```

Answer (score 0):

Much different ways to do this.

```
 $var = 0;
 $range_const = range(10,20);
 switch ($var) {
    case 1: $do = 5; break; # 1
    case 2: $do = 10; break; # 2
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5: $do = 15; break; # 3, 4, 5
    default:
      if ($var > 5 && $var < 10) { # High performance (6..9)
        $do = 20;
      } else if (in_array($var, $range_const, true)) { # Looks clear (10..20)
        $do = 25;
      } else { # NOT in range 1..20
        $do = -1;
      }
}
print($do);
```

There no direct range X..Y compares because $var checks to true in each step, but this allows do some nice cheating like this...

```
$in = create_function('$a,$l,$h', 'return $a>=$l && $a<=$h;');
$var = 4;
switch (true) {
  case ($var === 1): echo 1; break;
  case ($var === 2): echo 2; break;
  case $in($var, 3, 5): echo "3..5"; break;
  case $in($var, 6, 10): echo "6..10"; break;
  default: echo "else";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a more complex conditions, you can wrap them inside a function. Here's an oversimplified example:

```
$chartID = 20;
$somethingElse = true;

switch (switchRanges($chartID, $somethingElse)) {
  case "do this":
      echo "This is done";
      break;
  case "do that":
      echo "that is done";
      break;
  default:
      echo "do something different";
}

function switchRanges($chartID, $somethingElse = false)
{
    if (in_array($chartID, [20, 30]) && $somethingElse === true) {
        return "do this";
    }
    if (in_array($chartID, [20, 50]) && $somethingElse === false) {
        return "do that";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I would do it in a simple way.

```
switch($t = 100){
    case ($t > 99 && $t < 101):
        doSomething();
        break;
}
```

Comment: doSomething() will allways be called, because "switch($t = 100)" assigns 100 to $t

Comment: This is incorrect code, as you can't have `case x<10:` you can only have `case 10`.