# Grouping Numerical Values on PHP Switch

Tags: php

A quick look at the following PHP switches illustrates my problem, which is somewhat trivial...

```
switch($Rank)
{
 case 35:
 case 37:
 case 43:
 case 45:
 case 47:
 case 53:
 case 55:
 case 57:
 case 67:
 case 65:
 $MyOrd = substr($Order, 0, 3);
 break;
 default:
 $MyOrd = '';
 break;
}

switch($Rank)
{
 case 45:
 case 47:
 case 53:
 case 55:
 case 57:
 case 67:
 case 65:
 $MyFam = substr($Family, 0, 3);
 break;
 default:
 $MyFam = '';
 break;
}
```

I'd just like to condense my code. Is there a way to modify the first switch so that, instead of listing all those numbers, from 35 to 65, I can simply say "Give $MyOrd this value if $Rank = 35, 65 or any numerical value in between? So the new switch might look something like this:

```
switch($Rank)
{
 case 35-65:
 $MyOrd = substr($Order, 0, 3);
 break;
 default:
 $MyOrd = '';
 break;
}
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876620/php-switch-case-statement-to-handle-ranges

Comment: Use an `if` with a lesser/greater than comparison?

Comment: USE if else statement with OR comparison, that would make less code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't just replacing `switch()` with `if()` do the trick? Like:

```
if($Rank>34 && $Rank<66){
  $MyOrd = substr($Order, 0, 3);
}else{
  //do whatever you would do in default section
}
```