# PHP: issue with switch with range

Tags: php, switch-statement, range, numeric-ranges

I would like to differ between the following cases in PHP using a switch statement. 
**Can someone here help and tell me how I have to change this to get it working with numeric ranges (integers) ?**

- $myVar < 0
- $myVar < 10
- $myVar < 20
- $myVar < 30
- $myVar < 999
- default

**So far I have the following but guess this needs modification because of the ranges:**

```
switch($myVar)
{
    case(<0):
        // do stuff
        break;
    case(<10):
        // do stuff
        break;
    case(<20):
        // do stuff
        break;
    case(<30):
        // do stuff
        break;
    case(<999):
        // do stuff
        break;
    default:
        // do stuff
        break;
}
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim

Comment: Here's a *technique* http://stackoverflow.com/a/8876696/46675

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php#88643

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$myVar = 50;
switch (true) {
    case($myVar < 0):
        // do stuff
        break;
    case($myVar < 10):
        // do stuff
        break;
    case($myVar < 20):
        // do stuff
        break;
    case($myVar < 30):
        // do stuff
        break;
    case($myVar < 999):
        // do stuff
        break;
    default:
        // do stuff
        break;
}
```

There are a few good example about that in the comments of [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

Comment: One follow-up question on this, would this work the same way in JavaScript as well ?

Comment: Check out this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145723/how-can-i-use-ranges-in-a-switch-case-statement-using-javascript There you'll find a good source for this additional question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `in_array($myVar,range(100,200))` to check whether the value exists in the range.

```
$myVar = 50;
switch (true) {
    case(in_array($myVar,range(0,10))):
        // do stuff
        break;
    case(in_array($myVar,range(20,30))):
        // do stuff
        break;
    case(in_array($myVar,range(30,900))):
        // do stuff
        break;

    default:
        // do stuff
        break;
}
```