# php switch case statement to handle ranges with decimals / fractions

Tags: php, arrays, range, decimal, fractions

Using a case switch, how would I test to see if a decimal value is within a range?

This code appears to only check whole numbers.

Here is my code in an attempt to check decimals / fractions.

```
$my_num = 0.38;

switch(true) {
    case in_array($my_num, range(0, .20, 0.01)):
        $my_num_result = "It looks like your number is between 0 - 0.20!";
    break;
    case in_array($my_num, range(.21, .40, 0.01)):
        $my_num_result = "I am between .21 - 0.40!";
    break;
}

//Result: I am between .21 - 0.40!
echo $my_num_result;
```

This question is a continuation of [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876620/php-switch-case-statement-to-handle-ranges) but didn't address decimals.

Comment: `in_array()` really isn't a good way of checking floats, due to floating point imprecision; nor is using a switch statement particularly appropriate for this type of checking

Comment: I am open to suggestions for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach you can use *(if you don't have too many intervals to test)*, lets say you need to know which interval contains a number:

```
$intervals = [[0,.20],[.21,.40],[.41,.60]/*...*/];
$num = .32;

$message = 'I am between %s - %s!';

foreach ($intervals as $inter) {
    if ( $inter[0] <= $num && $num <= $inter[1] ) {
        vprintf($message, $inter);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I use this code if the defined variable is actually a completely new sentence?  `If between 1-20 $my_num_result = "some sentence"` `if between 21-30 $my_num_result = "some entirely new sentence"`

Comment: Then you can use the key for your `$intervals` array to identify that sentence

Comment: @Damien: or you can put it in the array:`$intervals=[[0,.20,'message'=>'sent1'],[.21,.40,'message'=>'sent2'],...]`