# Get user level depending on his/her points number PHP

Tags: php

I have a user points system which gives users points depending on some actions like selling a product or add new post etc...

I want to make a smarter PHP function to set a level for the user depending on his/her points.

Here's how I make this:

```
function get_user_level( $user_id ) {

$user_points = 3515 // Here I get the number of points that user have from the database

if ( $user_point >= 3000 ) {
    $level = '5';
} elseif ( $user_point >= 2000 ) {
    $level = '4';
} elseif ( $user_point >= 1500 ) {
    $level = '3';
} elseif ( $user_point >= 1000 ) {
    $level = '2';
} elseif ( $user_point >= 500 ) {
    $level = '1';
} else {
    $level = '0';
}

echo 'Level:' . $level;

}
```

The problem that my function seems very bad and not smarter I want to develop my function to upgrade user level for each 1000 point the user has (Making unlimited levels automatically).

Comment: better for code review SE

Comment: @ThisGuy No. `switch` is for comparing constant values, not ranges. Also won't address OP's question.

Comment: @deceze really? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876620/php-switch-case-statement-to-handle-ranges#8876696

Comment: @ThisGuy Yes, that's *possible*, but not what `switch` is really for. And I see no real advantage over `if..else` there.

Comment: @deceze ah I see.. and only advantage I suppose is readability .. will edity comment :)

Comment: Define a formula to derive the level mathematically from the points. If that's not possible you'll always end up with some cases you'll need to handle programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
if ($user_points < 2000)
{
    $level = floor($user_points / 500);
}
else
{
    $level = 4 + floor(($user_points-2000)/1000);
}
```

Which yields level 0-4 for 0-2000 points and then one additional level every 1000 points.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_user_level( $user_id ) {

$user_points = 3515; // Here I get the number of points that user have from the database

$level = intval($user_points/1000);
echo $level;

}
```

Comment: That changes the association between levels and points. Original: 3000 points => level 5, your answer: 3000 points => level 3

Comment: @hoffmale The question states _The problem that my function seems very bad and not smarter I want to develop my function to upgrade user level for each 1000 point the user has (Making unlimited levels automatically)._. This answers it well. Yes, it's not the same as the code shared, and that's intended as far as I can see.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a switch statement:

```
<?php

function get_user_level( $user_point ) 
{
    switch (true) {
        case $user_point >= 3000:
            return 5;
        case $user_point >= 2000:
            return 4;
        case $user_point >= 1500:
            return 3;
        case $user_point >= 1000:
            return 2;
        case $user_point >= 500:
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

echo get_user_level(3515); // outputs 5
```

See it here: https://3v4l.org/TmiAH

Comment: This is not, quote "making unlimited levels automatically".

Comment: neither it is, missed that part at the end of his question.

Comment: and what's the difference between your function and my function? xD I need to make an unlimited level and that's depending on user points.

Comment: yes i missed that part at the end of your question as i just said.